Motoman Robot self-collision detection and trajectory correction
I am working with a Motoman CSDA10F robot (dual arm robot). My goal is to receive a given trajectory from another project, and to convert that trajectory into a file that can move the robot (basically into an INFORM program file, which is the native programming langage of the CSDA10F).
A given trajectory that I receive is an array of size N*M, where N is the number of spacial point that the robot should follow to do the trajectory, and M is the number of joints of the robots (for each arm and the torso). So, each line is the succesive evolution of joints angles. So far, I was easily able to convert the trajectories into INFORM file that the robot can use to move. But the thing is that I do not check for any possible self-collision, nor I correct the trajectory if required.
So, given a margin that I could set up as will, I would like to be able to check for self-collision and correct the trajectory if necessary, before I do the convertion into INFORM file (i.e all that is offline). Ideally, i would like to do it in Python. Also, I have the URDF file, which i guess is required. So, maybe there is some librairies that already implement such things (I have heard about MoveIt or Pybullet ?) ? if no, what are the solutions ?
Also, (i) I cannot use ROS and (ii) another important aspects is that I need to keep the end point the trajectory unchanged (i.e the final position of the robot once it has finished moving), even if the trajectory had to be correct.
Maybe this is a simple question, but robotics is new to me to be honest.
